# Rename and move node one level up

Tags: xslt

I would like to rename and move node one level up if node value is a certain value.

So far I wrote this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="stock/images/image[main_image = 1]">
    <primary>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
    </primary>     
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<root>
<stock>
      <code>Apple</code>
      <images>
         <image>
            <img_file>1.jpg</img_file>
            <main_image>1</main_image>
         </image>
         <image>
            <img_file>2.jpg</img_file>
            <main_image>0</main_image>
         </image>
      </images>
</stock>         
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root>
<stock>
      <code>Apple</code>
      <images>
         <primary>
            <img_file>1.jpg</img_file>
            <main_image>1</main_image>
         </primary>
         <image>
            <img_file>2.jpg</img_file>
            <main_image>0</main_image>
         </image>
      </images>
</stock>         
</root>
```

It is almost good, but I would like to move `<primary>` node one level up, outside of `<images>`, like:

```
<root>
<stock>
      <code>Apple</code>
      <primary>
            <img_file>1.jpg</img_file>
            <main_image>1</main_image>
      </primary>
      <images>
         <image>
            <img_file>2.jpg</img_file>
            <main_image>0</main_image>
         </image>
      </images>
</stock>         
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="stock[images[image[main_image = 1]]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[not(self::images)]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="images/image[main_image = 1]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="images"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="images">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::image[main_image = 1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="stock/images/image[main_image = 1]">
        <primary>
             <xsl:apply-templates />
        </primary>     
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. @michael.hor257k answer works good too, but this one is more universal.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stock">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="code"/>
        <primary>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="images/image[main_image = 1]/*"/>
        </primary>
        <images>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="images/image[not(main_image = 1)]"/>
        </images>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This is assuming a primary image always exists. Otherwise you would need to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stock">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="code"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="images/image[main_image = 1]" mode="primary"/>
        <images>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="images/image[not(main_image = 1)]"/>
        </images>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image" mode="primary">
    <primary>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </primary>     
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```